# What's "ambiguous" here and how do I fix it?

Tags: haskell, import, variable-names

I'm told to write a function that would check if the punctuations in a string are all spaces. i.e.:

```
haskell> f "Hello my name is Brad"
True

haskell> f "Hello my name is Brad!"
False
```

I wrote an auxiliary function as follows,

```
import Data.Char
isPunc x = not (isDigit x || isAlpha x)
```

which was accepted by Haskell and worked fine. But as soon as I used it in the following function,

```
--function f defined
f :: String -> Bool
f xs = and [ x == ' ' | x <- xs, isPunc x]
```

it gives me this error:

```
ambiguous occurence 'isPunc', could mean "Main.isPunc" or "Data.Char. isPunc"
```

I am partially getting what it's complaining about, but having imported Data.Char, I don't really see why it's complaining.

Comment: @minitech Is there though? There is no function with that name in my installation and it's not listed in the docs either (though `isPunctuation` is). Note that the OP's code works fine for me.

Comment: Brad, did you post your code and the error message exactly as-is? You didn't name your function `isPunctuation` in your real code and then renamed it to `isPunc` in the code and in the error message when you posted it here, did you?

Answer (score 4):

(This post is written under the assumption that you really named your function `isPunctuation`, not `isPunc`)

It's ambiguous because Haskell doesn't know whether you're referring to your own `isPunctuation` function (`Main.isPunctuation`) or `Data.Char`'s `isPunctuation` function when you call `isPunctuation`. It's ambiguous *because* you imported `Data.Char` - if you hadn't imported it or if you imported it qualified, there would be no ambiguity as `isPunctuation` could only refer to `Main.isPunctuation`.

To fix the ambiguity, either don't import `isPunctuation` from `Data.Char` (by changing the import line to `import Data.Char hiding (isPunctuation)`), import `Data.Char` qualified (so you have to refer to its functions as `Data.Char.functionName` rather than just `functionName`), or give your function a different name that doesn't conflict with anything from `Data.Char`.

Answer (score 0):

`Data.Char` module has a function by the name `isPunctuation`. The only way you are getting the error you mentioned is if you had named the function you were creating the same. The name you have given here is `isPunc`, which should be perfectly fine, but I think you actually used `isPunctuation.` Use a different name or use qualified import:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char
```